# drawing a circle of 10 circles in LyX

Tags: lyx

I was wondering if its possible to draw a circle of 10 circles while putting a value in each one of them. like the next picture contains(but 10 circles and without the main black circle):

[image]

**edit**: Thank you but I have some trouble with putting numbers in the circles. I want each circle to add a custom value. for example it the top one - 9.

Comment: Should be very easy with TikZ.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

using `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle(2cm);
  \foreach \a in {0,...,9}
    \draw (\a*36:2) circle (4mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**note:**

- above minimal working example (*mwe*) is independent from lyx. it can be used in any latex distribution as `miktex`, `texlive`, `mactex` etc.
- used document class `standalone` is handy for presentation small piece of code, specially images as is used in this case. however, the image code can be used in documents with any standard document class as `article`, `report` and `book` as well in specialised and advanced ones as `beamer`, memoir, ... only requirement is load package `tikz` in a document preamble.
- picture is drawn with use of package `tikz`, however besedie `tikz` exist other packages for drawing in `latex` as are `pstrick`, `metapost` etc
- picture is consist from two parts:

  - main circle (`\draw[very thick] (0,0) circle(2cm);`) where `2cm` determine its radius
  - set of ten circles on radius, which is drawn in the loop (`\foreach \a in {0,...,9}\draw (\a*36:2) circle (4mm);`) where for circles positioning are used polar coordinates: `(<angle>:<distance>)` (`<angle>` is calculated by `\a*36` = `\a*360/10`)
- image code is very elementary, however you can upgrade it with some "fancy stuffs as determine new variables for circles radius, number of small circles etc (i left this to other answers)

**addendum:**

for adding numbers or text in circles, as you ask in edited question, i suggest to use nodes with circle shape:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Num/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=9mm, inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle(2cm);
  \foreach  \n [count=\a from 0] in {1, 1.41, 1.73, 2, 3, 3.14, $\pi$, $\phi$, 1.61, 0.96}
    \node[Num] at (\a*36:2) {\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing a bit from Zarko's answer. You need to add `\usepackage{tikz}` in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. In your document, write the `tikzpicture` enviroment in an ERT (TeX code inset, add one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>). If you paste code into an ERT, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (Edit -> Paste special), to preserve line breaks.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i from 0] \txt in {1,3,7,42,3.14,17,$\pi$,$\phi$,1.618,1.41}
    \draw (\i*36:2) node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] {\txt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And just for fun, a slightly more automated version. The list of numbers are saved in a macro, the length of that list calculated, and the angle step in the polar coordinates calculated accordingly. Note that with this approach, entries that are not pure numbers, need to be placed in quotes, e.g. `"$\phi$"`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% array with list of numbers
\newcommand\mynumbers{{1,3,7,42,3.14,17,3,1.618,"$\phi$",1,100}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% calculate length of array
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NumofNums}{dim(\mynumbers)}
% use evaluate to extract element from array
% indexes starts at zero, hence \i-1, not \i
\foreach [evaluate={\txt=\mynumbers[\i-1]}] \i in {1,...,\NumofNums}
    % (a:r) is a polar coordinate
    \draw ({\i*360/\NumofNums}:2.2) node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.1cm] {\txt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand\mynumbers{{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NumofNums}{dim(\mynumbers)}
\foreach [evaluate={\txt=\mynumbers[\i-1]}] \i in {1,...,\NumofNums}
    \draw ({\i*360/\NumofNums}:2.2) node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.1cm] {\txt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks. Compile with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`.

### Basic

I directly specify each object position using polar representation `(radius;angle)`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \foreach \i in {0,36,...,330}
    {
        \pscircle[fillstyle=solid](2;\i){10pt}
        \rput(2;\i){\scriptsize\i}
    }
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

### Intermediate

I transform a group of origin-attached objects with `\uput` which behaves like the "sun-earth-moon" system.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \foreach \i in {0,36,...,330}
    {
        \uput{2}[\i](0,0)
        {
            \pscircle[fillstyle=solid]{10pt}
            \rput(0,0){\scriptsize\i}
        }
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Advanced

I simply specify how many points I want to create and PSTricks implicitly determines the angle increment of `36` degrees. The points can be on any arbitrary parameterized curves but in this case I choose a parameterized circle.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=11]{0}{TwoPi}{2*cos(t)|2*sin(t)}{P}
    \multido{\i=0+1,}{\Pnodecount}
    {
        \pscircle[fillstyle=solid](P\i){10pt}
        \rput(P\i){\scriptsize\the\numexpr\i*36}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

They produce the same output as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the number are in progression:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=126]
\foreach \a in {0,...,9} \draw (\a*36:2) circle (4mm) node {-\a}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If they are not, modify the `\foreach` in

```
\foreach \a/\descr in {0/-9,1/<your other value>, <etc.>}
```

And use `\descr` as node text.